# matplotlib breaks str( ) in Python 2.7.3 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, string, matplotlib

Here is an illustration of the problem in iPython. This is reproducible in every other Python shell I have tried.

```
In [1]: a = 1e-6

In [2]: str(a)
Out[2]: '1e-06'

In [3]: import matplotlib as mpl

In [4]: str(a)
Out[4]: '1e-06'

In [5]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [6]: str(a)
Out[6]: '1e-06'

In [7]: plt.plot(1.0)
Out[7]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x262a850>]

In [8]: str(a)
Out[8]: '1e-06'

In [9]: plt.show()

In [10]: str(a)
Out[10]: 'ERR'
```

And here are the relevant version numbers.

```
In [11]: mpl.__version__
Out[11]: '1.2.0'

In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: np.__version__
Out[13]: '1.6.2'
```

This is happening on my XP Professional lab computer running Python 2.7.3 and Microsoft Visual Express 2008 C++ and Basic. I have no idea how to begin tracking down the problem.

Comment: That is very strange.  I can't reproduce the behavior (Python 2.7.3, Windows 7, same versions of mpl and numpy).  You mention Visual Express.  Did you compile matplotlib yourself?  Can you do `str` by itself to see if `str` has been set to some strange object somehow, or `a` by itself, or `type(a)` to see if it's been changed?  Also, what backend are you using?

Comment: Could you print out `type(a), id(a), type(str), id(str)` before and after the call to `plt.show()`?

Comment: I mentioned Visual Express because I had a terrible time setting up several packages, including matplotlib. I ended up installing it from the executable. I suspect the root of this problem is in my matplotlib installation/C compiler.

Comment: Here is the output of `type(a), id(a), type(str), id(str)` before `(float, 14616600, type, 505348768)` and after `(float, 14616600, type, 505348768)` the `plt.show()` command.

Comment: @NikHartman: And you say this happens in every Python shell?  Even the plain command-line Python interpreter?  What mpl backend is set?

Comment: Yes. This happens in the plain command-line Python interpreter as well. `plt.get_backend()` yields `'TkAgg'`

Comment: @NikHartman: Have you tried completely removing matplotlib and reinstalling fron the EXE installer?

Comment: I have not tried reinstalling from the executable, it seemed like an unsatisfying solution. I did try the same code with `mpl.use('Agg')` between lines 3 and 4 and found the error vanished. Clearly, this is not a full solution since it does not actually display the plot.

Comment: Based on how much trouble I had setting everything up to begin with, I decided to reinstall Python, numpy, scipy, and matplotlib from scratch. This error still exists. I will post an answer if I ever figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

`Enthought` answered this question by existing.  It's not the most satisfying solution, but I couldn't justify spending days and days trying to track down the root of the problem described above.